# How to combine xargs with git show --name-only

Tags: git

```
$ git lg1 --author=name . |awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
8901004
4e4c435
ab9e126

$ git lg1 --author=name . |awk -F' ' '{print $2}'|xargs -I{} git show {} --name-only
fatal: ambiguous argument '8901004': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Question> How should I do here to fix the git complaint?

Note: git lg1 [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Comment: I think the problem does not have to do with xargs. If you use `git show 8901004 --name-only` alone you should get the same error. Note that the error message tells you what you could try: add another `--` to the git command.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I could run `git show 8901004 --name-only` without problems.

Comment: I can run your command with `git lg1` just fine on a repo.

Answer (score 0):

This runs just fine in a git 2.28 Windows bash:

```sh
MINGW64 /c/git/git (master)
$ git lg -2 --author=name . |awk -F' ' '{print $2}'|grep 8|xargs -I{} git show {} --name-only
```

I tried with `--name-only` or `git show --name-only {}`, without adding any '--' at the end, and it does work.